# How to make a thread contain a loop using mutexes to control flow?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a homework assignment and I've hit a wall. The assignment is to use 2 threads with controlling mutex to reduce a number x over a loop of 5 iterations.

The first thread does x=x-5
The second thread does x = x/5 
 
The proper result should reduce x to 5 from 19530 over 5 iterations alternating between thread1 and thread2 at each iteration.
I have the following result as of now:

> Thread1: x = 19525
>   Thread1: x = 19520
>   Thread1: x = 19515
>   Thread1: x = 19510
>   Thread1: x = 19505

From above it is clear that my second thread is not only not doing it's job but it's not doing anything at all.

Below is my code, it is written in C++ but the style is using the tools we learned in class which is how one would do it in C but it should work the same either way.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void *first(void *);
void *second(void *);

pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int x = 19530; // global var that is being manipulated
int i = 1; // counter for the loops

int main() {
    int t1, t2;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    if((t1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, first, NULL))) {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", t2);
    }

    if((t2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, second, NULL))) {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", t2);
    }

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    return(0);
}

void *first(void *){ // function for thread1
  for(; i <=5; i++){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
  x = x-5;
  cout << "Thread1: x = " << x << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
  }
}

void *second(void *){ // function for thread2
  for(; i<=5; i++){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
  x = x/5;
  cout << "Thread2: x = " << x << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
  }
}
```

Note I am brand new to the concept threads and mutex. And I'd prefer to stick to the way I have learned in class which I believe is called "the C way".

Comment: I am afraid this code might not do exactly what you want. thread#1 can run to finish before thread#2 even starts - aka the "alternating" is not guaranteed to happen. You need to rethink your design and enforce it.

Comment: Don't spam tags for unrelated languages!

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. But I guess the fundamental problem I have is how to make thread1 iterate and then exit in a way that calls thread2. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Olaf It seemed appropriate to include both C and C++ because my code is in c++. I didn't want to tag C and get downvotes and mean comments about why I'm not including C++ since I am writing in it because I've had that happen before.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Your code is apparently C++, so using the C tag is definiively wrong. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. And teaching C-coding **style** in C++ sheds a very bad light on the course.

Comment: The simple solution to force alternation is to use two mutexes (or two semaphores).

Comment: @rcgldr I'm not following but that's an idea. I'll try working on it like that. I never even considered using 2 of them. Should I have each mutex correspond to a thread but in such a way that thread1 unlocks thread2 and viceversa?

Comment: @KazRodgers - `thread1 unlocks thread2 and viceversa?` Yes, each thread would have a mutex that it wait for, update x, then unlock the other thread's mutex, then loop back and wait for it's mutex to get unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rclgdr who commented above I was able to answer my own question the following code works as intended:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void *first(void *);
void *second(void *);

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // thread1 mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // thread2 mutex

int x = 19530; // global var that is being manipulated

int main() {
    cout << "x = " << x << endl << endl;
    int t1, t2;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    if((t1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, first, NULL))) {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", t2);
    }

    if((t2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, second, NULL))) {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", t2);
    }

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    return(0);
  }

void *first(void *){ // function for thread1
  for(int i = 1; i <=5; i++){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
  x = x-5;
  cout << "Iteration " << i <<endl;
  cout << "Thread1: x = " << x << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
  }
}

void *second(void *){ // function for thread2
  for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
  x = x/5;
  cout << "Thread2: x = " << x << endl << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
  }
}
```